# Apache shiro Property 'sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout' does not exist

Tags: apache, security, jakarta-ee, web, shiro

I am facing another problem when I try to set session timeout in `shiro.ini` like this:

```
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 3600000
```

I get an exception:

> 11:19:44,363 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Property
>   'sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout' does not exist for object of
>   type org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager.

I am using shiro 1.2.2, if you are familiar with this exception please advise.

Answer (score 8):

you are missing the one line in shiro.ini file.

```
 securityManager.sessionMode=native
```

after adding this above line it will work.for full configuration session in shiro.ini file.

```
 sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
 securityManager.sessionMode=native
 securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 60000
 securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer will now result in a warning that the `sessionMode` property is deprecated.

Use this instead:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 3600000
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```